# Excel autosave versioning

Tags: microsoft-excel, backup, microsoft-excel-2007, version-control

Is there any feature/option built into excel that allows the auto-saving of version documents.

I am developing a vba app at the moment (first one) and for those times that something breaks or there is a piece of code that i used and then removed, i like to take a different version every half hour or so, but this currently involves going:

1. File > Save As > mydoc v87.xlsm
2. File > save as > myDoc.xlsm

Especially for the macro, if i didnt have to change the file name to create a version that would be fantastic.

I realise there is 3rd party software that will do what i want, but a built in feature would be excellent.

If not built directly into office, is there a local option available in windows 7. With extremely strict group policy and very minimal server space, the server option is not looking very appealing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This SO post has a macro that might do precisely what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454235/macro-to-save-and-version-control-file

If installing Dropbox is an option, it's ability to browse to earlier versions is great for exactly this sort of problem.

From [How do I recover old versions of files?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/11)

[image: dropbox versioning snapshot]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That code should do exactly what i want. My preferred option is dropbox, but our silly group policy forbids it ('security issues'). Cheers!

Comment: That macro is close. it saves the file, but i need it to return the file back to its original filename. Will modify and see if i can get it to work. The only thing im not sure how to do is to get the version number if it is not appended to the current workbook? Thankyou very much for pointing in the right direction.